# how to refer jars present in other war file in my own webb applications manifest file

Tags: java

My requirement is I have to refer the jars present in other war file in my web application.

I am thinking to edit the manifest file of my web application to add the jars of other war file, but I do not know exactly what to add in the manifest file.

Could any one please help me on this.

Comment: Is it not possible to add the jar to your web application directly?

Comment: I thought to add directly but it is not possible.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You web application should be running inside at least a *Servlet Container*, right?

So you have to move your *second webapp* jars inside the library directory of your Application Server (e.g. *lib* for Tomcat AS) and that way the classes under those ***jars*** will be available for both web application (even all web application running in you AS).

*Note:* It is already a bad practice to package a common dependencies under a *war* archive as those should be shared among multiple contexts, so you should review you packaging strategy.

### Edit: How to declare a Shared classpath in Tomcat

To define a shared classpath in Tomcat AS so that all your contexts have access to:

- Navigate to your server home (*$CATALINA_HOME*) and open the *catalina.properties* file under the *conf/* directory.
- Look for the shared class loader section and add / modify shared loader to look as follows:

  ```
  shared.loader="/path-to-shared-classes"
  ```

*You need to look for the classpath form rules*, yours may be *`"$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/middlewar/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar"`*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But unfortunately my manager wants to deploy a seperate war file. Could you please tell me steps to solve the issue with seperate war file.

Comment: How are you packaging your applications? Are you using some build tool?

Comment: I am not using build tool. It is a simple web application, so exporting war file from eclipse IDE

Comment: And where is the other application? The same case applies and it is an Eclipse Project?
Also what those dependencies are then? Jars into libraries or what?
You may need to provide detailed description, even a snapshot will be highly welcomed of both projects.

Comment: Let me Explain you clearly :
Actually we are developing a mobile application using a Kony studio.
I am working at server side development using kony studio(it is nothing but a plugin on eclipse), it is a middleware development.

we install kony server on top of tomcat server. so in tomcat's "webapps" directory there will be
a "middleware" directory(because we have installed kony server on top of tomcat).
Now whatever the services I develop for my mobile application, I will place those .jar files in tomcat's 
webapps/middlewar/web-inf/lib direcotry.

Comment: Here comes the requirement, my manager wants me to bundle all our .jar files as .war file and deploy that .war
file. Now he wants me to refer these .war file from kony's "middlewar" application.

Comment: I have updare my answer describing how to declare a shared class path for your webapps. Note I have not tested it for your particular case, so you may need to do it for me and feed me with results ;)

Comment: Hi Tmarwen,                                                                      your suggestion really worked, thank you very much for that. I have one doubt, since my jars are placed as shared library in tomcat, means these will be loaded by all web applications deployed on the server. Would not it be a problem.

Comment: Since it resolved the issue, please accept the answer and even upvote it so it will be eligible for future visitors :)
As long as you control what application goes to the server, there will be no issue and it all depends on you components design, cannot judge that simple.